# misc.imread and misc.imsave changes pixel values

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, scipy

I am:

- reading a grayscale image,
- performing normalization of all pixel values and then
- saving the image.

When I reopen the image I see different pixel values.

My code snippet:

```
image = misc.imread('lena.jpg')  
maximum = np.max(image) # finds maximum pixel value of image  
img = np.divide(image, maximum) # divide every pixel value by maximum
# scale every pixel value between 0 and 127
img_scale = np.round(img * (np.power(2,7)-1)).astype(int)  
misc.imsave('lena_scaled.jpg', img_scale)  
img_reopen = misc.imread('lena_scaled.jpg')
```

When I compare `img_scale` and `img_reopen` I get different values:

```
By executing np.max(img_scale), I get 127.
By executing np.max(img_reopen), I get 255
By executing img_scale[0][0], I get [82,82,82]
By executing img_reopen[0][0], I get [156][156][156]
```

**Question**

Why do the pixel values get changed after saving the image and reopening it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imsave function rescales the image when it saves to the disk.

`misc.imsave` function uses `bytescale` under the hood to rescale image to the full range (0,255).

That's why you get `np.max` 255 when you reopen. Please refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html).

**Follow-up:**
To preserve your values without rescaling, you can try use `misc.toimage` function and save the resulting as follows,

```
im = misc.toimage(img_scale, high=np.max(img_scale), low=np.max(img_scale)
im.save('lena_scaled.jpg')
```

When you read the `'lena_scaled.jpg'` with `misc.imsave` you can try use the following:

```
misc.imread('lena_scaled.jpg', mode='I')
```

I - ‘L’ (8-bit pixels, black and white)
which I believe would work for your grayscale image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: scipy mentions that toimage is deprecated. Use Pillow and the fromarray function:For example to save the result as uint8 images:
`Image.fromarray(np.uint8(numpyarr)).save(resfilepath)`